# How to get value from column that was changed by trigger

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a before insert trigger (MySQL) on a table that changes the value of a column.

But after doing the `->save()` that the triggers its supposed to be done, if I do `object->number` (number is the column that was set on the trigger) I get nothing, while if I look on the database number was set.

I dont know why it happens if the autoincrement id is also set during the insert and that one I can get it.

Thanks for the help

```
$object = new Table();
$object->col1 = 'hello';
$object->save();
echo $object->number;
```

Number is the column that was changed by the before insert trigger

Here is the trigger's code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`homestead`@`%` TRIGGER `database`.`Table_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET New.number = (SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` where relation_id = New.relation_id);
END
```

Comment: let us see your code from tigger

Comment: The `$model` is saved and it remembers the state of the object for that request. It's not reloaded from MySQL afterwards. You'd need to do `$model->save(); $model = Model::find($id); echo $model->number;` in order to get the new value of number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you called `save` the current values on model will be persisted to the database and Laravel ORM doesn't reflect the changes done by the database system unless it is fetched again manually.

To get the updated values you can use the `fresh` method.

```
$object->fresh()->number;
```